# Conditions for conclusion

Tags: sample-size, sample

A study had shown that annual income on average was significantly higher among men than women for people over 30 years old in Portugal. The results were from 312 Portuguese men and 62 Portuguese women. The samples were chosen (not randomly) by the researchers.

Can we conclude that, in general, the annual income for Portuguese men is
higher than the average income for Portuguese women?

I think that we can *not* conclude this because of the following two reasons:

1. The samples for both men and women were too low.
2. The samples were *not* chosen randomly.

Am I correct? Why or why not?

Comment: In what context does this question arise (does this fall under [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), for example)? ... The lack of random sampling makes it impossible to generalize from the sample, so I agree with your "2". With good sampling practices, even such sample sizes as those might be adequate. However, note that there's nothing to indicate the samples are for people over 30; that might be another problem.

Comment: The key to whether 1) is correct or not is in the concept of *significance*. The key to whether 2) is correct or not is in the concept of *randomness*.

Comment: OK, I will take it off @Glen_b

Comment: @PeterFlom Sometimes the OP will be quite explicit that it is self-study but without adding the tag, and in that case I think it's reasonable to add. I agree that it sure seems to be.

Comment: Re reason (1): How can you tell the sample sizes were too small ("too low")? What do you think would be sufficiently large sample sizes for this study? What is your basis for thinking this?